# Where can I level Puppetmaster from 75 to 80 solo?

Tags: final-fantasy-11

What are some good camp sites in Final Fantasy XI where I can solo past level 75 on my Puppetmaster? Preferably ones that don't require a Scholar support job, since I haven't leveled that job yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Campaign!

Seriously though, why level solo anymore? Have you tried an Abyssea alliance? They get on the order of 40-45k/hr once they get up to speed; People are going from 75-80 in the matter of a single afternoon, plus getting a merit or two in there. Since normal party dynamics don't matter as much, job selection is a lot more flexible. Hang out in Whitegate for a bit, and you'll probably see a few shouts for people putting one together.

Comment: It didn't take long after the release of Abyssea for it to became the hottest thing since TP burns. A 14-hour Abyssea super-marathon netted me around 500k EXP and, tragically, pretty much put me off ever playing FFXI again. ;)